# Is there are function $f$ on the positive integers, so that $f(f(n))=n+1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, functions

Can one find $f: \mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ so that $f(f(n))=n+1\quad \forall n \in\mathbb{N} $ ?

My intuition says it should not be possible, but I don't really see a way to prove that, right now.

Comment: Try to explain your intuition

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $f(f(n))=n+1$, $f(f(f(n)))=f(n+1)=f(n)+1$. So we see 
$$f(n)=f(1)+n-1.$$
Now we look at what this means for $f(1)$ by using $f(f(n))=n+1.$ So we get

$$f(f(1)+n-1)=2f(1)+n=n+1.$$

So $f(1)=\frac{1}{2}$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Suppose that $f$ is such a function. Let $k=f(1)$; clearly $k>1$. Then $f(k)=1+1=2$, so $f(2)=k+1$, so $f(k+1)=2+1=3$, and so on.

- Show by induction on $n$ that $f(n)=k+n-1$ for all $n\ge 1$.
- Show by induction on $n$ that $f(n)=n-k+2$ for all $n\ge k$.

Now combine the two to get a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(j) = \ell$ then we have $f(f(j))= f(\ell)$ hence $f(j+1) = \ell + 1$. Then the entirety of the function is determined by $f(1)$. So if $f(1) = k$ the map is just $f(n) = n + k - 1$. But of course then

> $$f(f(n)) = (n + k -1) + k - 1 = n + 2k -2.$$

But this is $n + 2(k-1)$ cannot be equal to $n+1$ as $2(k-1)$ is even.