# How can I attempt this FE

Tags: functional-equations

Prove that there is no function f : ℕ→ℕ such that f (f (n)) = n + 1. Here ℕ is the positive integers {1, 2, 3,...}.

I have messed around with the FE but can't seem to produce anything meaningful. I found the solution online which states but I'm having trouble following the part where it states that the former yields f
2
(N):

Let M = {2,3,...} = N\ {1}. Then f
2
(N) = M and therefore f(N) = N or
M. The former yields f
2
(N) = N, which is not the case, so we must have
the latter which yields f(M) = M. It follows that f
2
(M) = M and we have
a contradiction, so there is no such f , as required.

Link is added below:

https://www.math.vt.edu/people/plinnell/Vtregional/E18/index.html

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please provide a link to the solution you found online as it could help us to better answer your question. Thanks.

Comment: https://www.math.vt.edu/people/plinnell/Vtregional/E18/index.html

Comment: Thanks for providing a link. However, it only has your question stated as question #$3$. I don't see any solution for this question, or any other listed questions, on that page.

Comment: https://www.math.vt.edu/people/plinnell/Vtregional/solutions.pdf

Comment: Solutions have been uploaded; I didn't attach it at first as the solutions are all the way at the bottom.

Comment: Also could you explain how they can deduce that "Then f 2 (N) = M and therefore f(N) = N or M."

Comment: I just worked on this one yesterday. I will post an alternate solution.

Comment: By the way, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1936098/is-there-are-function-f-on-the-positive-integers-so-that-ffn-n1 - though your question is not a duplicate of this, because you have a specific point of confusion.

Comment: (())=+1 , ((()))=(+1)=()+1. Sorry to bother you, but how can we deduce that ()+1 is equal to all the rest of the statements?

Answer (score 1):

Note that 
\begin{align*}
1 \mapsto k_1 &\mapsto 2\\
2 \mapsto k_2 &\mapsto 3\\
3 \mapsto k_3 &\mapsto 4\\
\vdots \mapsto \vdots &\mapsto\vdots\\
r \mapsto k_r &\mapsto r+1\\
\vdots \mapsto \vdots &\mapsto\vdots\\
\end{align*}
As you can see from the composition mapping, $M=\{2,3,4,5, \ldots\}$ is definitely in the range of $f$. So $M \subseteq f(\Bbb{N})$.

**Question:** is $1 \in f(\Bbb{N})$?

Note that from the *second part* of the composition, it is clear that $1 \not\in f(\Bbb{N})$. Thus the range $f(\Bbb{N})=M$.

This means for all $i$, $k_i \in M$. Said differently $f(M)=M$. But then $f(f(M))=M$. If this was true then how will $2$ be in the range of $f$?

Answer (score 0):

Since $f(n+1)= (f \circ (f \circ f))(n)=((f \circ f) \circ f)(n)= f(n)+1,$ we have $f(n)=n+c$ where $c=f(1)-1 \in \mathbb{Z}.$ But then $c=1/2$ by substitution, a contradiction.